# why is Java Processbuilder 4000 times slower at running commands then Python Subprocess.check_output

Tags: java, python, performance, subprocess, processbuilder

I was trying to write a wrapper for a third party C tool using Java processbuilder. I need to run this process builder millions of times. But, I found something weird about the speed.

I already have a wrapper for this third party tool C tool for python. In python, the wrapper uses the python subprocess.check_output.

So, I ran the java wrapper 10000 times with same command. Also, ran the python wrapper 10000 time with same command.

With python, my 10000 tests ran in about 0.01 second.

With java processbuilder, it ran in 40 seconds.

Can someone explain why I am getting large difference in speed between two languages?

You try this experiment with a simple command like "time".

Comment: Are you _reading_ from the streams that Java gives you? If not, this would certainly explain the problem.

Comment: if i need the output from the processbuilder, I am reading the streams that java gives me. But, even if I dont read the streams. For example, if we have java program like this. line 1: Processbuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("time"); line 2: Process p = pb.start(); This alone took 40 secs compared to python is took only 0.01.

Comment: Show us the complete code for the wrappers.  Under the covers, you must be doing something that is significantly different.  Running 10,000 commands in 0.01 seconds seems implausibly fast.

Comment: are you sure `check_output` doesn't raise an exception immediately? It takes ~0.3 seconds to start 10000 child processes and to read some output from them using [C program that calls fork(), write(), read(), select() directly (compile with `-DN=10000`)](https://gist.github.com/zed/7623724) i.e., as @Stephen C said: 0.01 seconds per 10000 processes seems too fast.

Comment: I was courious so i ran 10.000 processes in Java which took 42.6 seconds. But can you post the code from your Java and Python program.

Comment: I am sorry to bother you guys. I though python was using subprocess for a library I was using. But, it has some bindings. It confused me in the beginning because the library folder as a python script called wrappers.py which spawned a new child processor using subprocessor. Then, it also had a another file called bindings.py. The library I am using is this: https://github.com/benpruitt/primer3-py. I guess I need to learn to the JAVA JNI to make this faster.

Comment: @MSUcomprotein: you should probably [add your comment as an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) (the python is faster because it doesn't spawn subprocesses i.e., `check_output()` is not used actually).

Answer (score 0):

It seems like python doesn't spawn subprocess. Which is why it was faster.

I am sorry with confusion.

thank you